# Community specific reasons for closing only shows EL&U and Writing Meta SE options

Tags: feature-request, bug, migration, close-reasons, vote-to-close

A reason for closing is that the question should belong on a different SE site. The pop-up box only gives you two possible sites to migrate the question to, Writing Meta and EL&U.

Could we include a search bar to pick any SE site to migrate to instead of just 2 options? Some of the questions we get here would be a better fit for SE sites other than Meta and EL&U, like Law and Literature SE.

**Update:** I have now asked [this question on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359737/could-we-make-the-migration-search-function-for-moderators-be-made-available-to) as a feature request.

**Update 2:** My question on Meta SE has now been closed as a duplicate to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration).

**Update 3:** I have now asked [this follow-up question](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/follow-up-on-increasing-the-possible-migration-routes-for-writing-se).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could we include a search bar to pick any SE site to migrate to instead of just 2 options?

This is actually what we mods have. While regular users have only a limited list of options, moderators can migrate a question to any site on the network they choose - even other sites' Metas! Of course, since my close-votes are binding, I have to be *absolutely certain* I'm sending a question to the right place when I do this.

My understanding is that the migration paths for regular users are only for the most common migrations, so they can be handled by the community without the need for a mod to step in. Mods are then only required for the (theoretically) rare occasions where a question needs to be migrated to a site that's not on the list. The list *can* be extended, but only to a maximum of five or so.

My suggestions to you would be:

- If you want a question to be migrated to a site that doesn't have a migration path, flag it for moderator attention with an explanation of which site you think it should be migrated to, and we can take care of the rest.
- If you want a new migration path to be added, you can start a separate discussion here on Meta and state your case. (I'd personally advocate a migration path to Literature.SE, but would like to check the stats for how many questions we've migrated there.)
- If you want the migration search function for moderators to be made available to regular users, you would have to post a feature request on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). That would likely be a network-wide change, and isn't something I have the power to do.

Answer (score 1):

Moderators have the power to add additional target sites to the list that you have quoted (except on beta sites).

As already suggested, you could raise a proposal to add a specific site.  If questions are regularly being migrated to a site that is not on the list, then adding it makes sense.

Moderators are provided with a lot of guidance regarding migration of questions.  There are more conditions under which it should not done than conditions under which it should.  My understanding is that this is why the ability to migrate anywhere is not made more widely available.